# Ancient texts/ scriptures on matas

Tags: scripture, devi

Some of the texts that I know of are **devi bhagwat mahapuran**, **devi mahatmya**. What are some other texts dedicated to matas?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia? See [History_of_Shaktism#Puranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Shaktism#Puranas), [Shakta_Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakta_Upanishads) and [Upapurana#The_Shakta_Upapuranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upapurana#The_Shakta_Upapuranas).

Comment: @sv. are there no puranas? only upapuranas?

Comment: @juztcode, could you elaborate on your question? What are you looking for and gives us some examples of what you found.

Comment: @TheMatrix , just as sv has pointed out above, I'm looking for texts for matas, e.g. texts may be related to gau mata, bhu mata, maa shakti, maa durga, maa saraswati, maa lakshmi. I have found texts like stotras and prayers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some Śākta Upaniṣads and their summaries from [*A Descriptive Catalogue of the Sanskrit Manuscripts, Vol. 1, Part 3*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n1/mode/2up):

> - [Tripurātāpanīyopaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n151/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad teaches that Śakti is the Supreme Being and to offer
>   worship unto Her as such, a Mantra and a Yantra are also given herein.
>   It concludes with an exposition of the oneness of the Sentient
>   Principle which is conceived to form the foundation of the universe
>   and all its varied phenomena.
> - [Tripuropaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n155/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad teaches that the worship of Śakti with the aid of the
>   Śrīcakra and the Śrīvidyā is the means of attaining salvation The
>   Vāmācāra form of Śakti worship is also adverted to incidentally with a
>   view to censure it.
> - [Devyupaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n165/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad teaches that Devī or Durgā or Śakti is the Supreme
>   Being. Devī Mantra is herein taught to be the means of conducting her
>   worship and thereby obtaining salvation.
> - [Bahvṛcopaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n209/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad teaches that Devī is the Supreme Being from whom
>   proceed all the gods and all the various beings in the universe it
>   describes her as all pervading and endeavors to identify the meaning
>   of certain Devī mantras with that of the Mahāvākyas
> - [Bhāvanopaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n231/mode/2up)
>
>   In this Upaniṣad the body is likened unto the Śrīcakra by the
>   respective identification of their various parts and the various
>   activities of the mind are stated to constitute the worship of this
>   Śrīcakra which is a mystic figure used in the worship of Śakti. The
>   name of the Upaniṣad is due to the fact that in it there is the
>   Bhāvanā or conception of the body as the Śrīcakra.
> - [Sarasvatīrahasyopaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n311/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad teaches the worship of Sarasvatī, the goddess of
>   learning, by means of ten Ṛks in the Vedic style and ten stanzas in
>   the Śloka style and explains the Ṛṣi, Chandas, Devatā, Prayoga, Nyāsa,
>   &c. in relation to those Ṛks for conducting her worship.
> - [Sītopaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n317/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad identifies Sītā with the primordial matter Prakṛti and
>   mentions that all the things in the universe have proceeded from her.
> - [Saubhāgyalakṣmyupaniṣad](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.367292/page/n325/mode/2up)
>
>   This Upaniṣad describes the worship of Devī by means of the Śrīsūkta,
>   the manner of meditating upon Her, and the characteristics of the
>   Navacakra to be used in connection with Her worship.

You can read the full English translations of these in A. G. Krishna Warrier's [*The Śākta Upaniṣads*](https://archive.org/details/KRI186TheSaktaUpanishadsTr.ByA.G.KrishnaWarrierAdyarLibrary/page/n1/mode/2up).

As for Śākta Purāṇas/Upapurāṇas, [*The Cultural Heritage of India, Vol. II*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.284245/page/n307/mode/2up) lists the following.

> **THE ŚĀKTA UPAPURĀṆAS**
>
> ([R. C. Hazra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._C._Hazra))
>
> Among the Upapurāṇas dealing with Śakti worship the following have
> come down to us:
>
> - Devī Purāṇa,
> - Kālikā Purāṇa,
> - Mahā-Bhāgavata,
> - Devī-Bhāgavata,
> - Bhagavatī Purāṇa,
> - Caṇḍī Purāṇa (or Caṇḍikā Purāṇa), and
> - Satī Purāṇa (also called Kālī or Kālikā Purāṇa).
>
> Of these, the first four, which are more important, are now available in print, and the rest in manuscripts. It is remarkable that all the Śākta Upapurāṇas mentioned above have been much influenced by the Tantras.

Comment: do you think you can mark your answer as community wiki so people can keep adding more information as they find it?

Comment: @juztcode I prefer others write their own answers. Once I make it a wiki, users can edit/delete existing content too.

Answer (score 1):

So, through this question you mean to ask that if there are any Sacred/Holy texts based on only Mata's/Devi's/Goddesses.

Answer to your question --------------

> The Vedas include numerous goddesses including Parvati (power), Prithvi (earth), Aditi (cosmic moral order), Vāc (sound), Nirṛti (destruction), Ratri (night), Aranyani (forest), and bounty goddesses such as Dinsana, Raka, Puramdhi, Parendi, Bharati, Mahi among others are mentioned in the Rigveda.

> However, the goddesses are not discussed as frequently as gods (Devas). Devi Parvati, appears in late Vedic texts dated to be pre-Buddhist, but verses dedicated to her do not suggest that her characteristics were fully developed in the Vedic era. All gods and goddesses are distinguished in the Vedic times, but in the post-Vedic texts, particularly in the early medieval era literature, they are ultimately seen as aspects or manifestations of one Devi, the Supreme power.

> Devi is the supreme being in the Shakta tradition of Hinduism, while in the Smarta Tradition, she is one of the five primary forms of Brahman that is revered.In other Hindu traditions, Devi embodies the active energy and power of Deva, and they always appear together complementing each other, such as Parvati with Shiva in Shaivism, Saraswati with Brahma in Brahmanism, and Lakshmi with Vishnu in Vaishnavism.

> **The Devi-inspired philosophy is propounded in many Hindu texts, such as the Devi Upanishad, which states that Shakti is essentially Brahman (ultimate metaphysical Reality), from her arise Prakṛti (matter) and Purusha (consciousness), she is bliss and non-bliss, the Vedas and what is different from it, the born and the unborn, and all of the universe. Shakti is Parvati, Shiva’s consort. She is also mentioned as the creative power of Shiva in Tripura Upanishad, Bahvricha Upanishad, and Guhyakali Upanishad.**

For more information -------
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi

Comment: In the first paragraph you mention goddess names: Parvati (power), Prithvi (earth), Aditi (cosmic moral order), Vāc (sound), Nirṛti (destruction), Ratri (night) .. etc. Do you think there are specific texts attributed to them?

Comment: Some of the content in your answer appears copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi#History). It's ok to copy-paste but you need to credit the author/source. See [How to reference material written by others](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: FYI, you can use [blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) if you are directly quoting Wikipedia or any other source.

Comment: Pure copy paste answers are discouraged. Visit [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/277) for more information.

Comment: Hey, I didn't copy paste !